# How to load packages in R

Tags: r, tm

I have successfully installed the `tm` package, which is located in: `C:\Users\JustinLiang\Documents\R\win-library\3.0`

After type `library()`, it shows me the R packages available list:

> Packages in library ‘C:/Users/JustinLiang/Documents/R/win-library/3.0’:
>
> tm                      Text Mining Package
>
> Packages in library ‘C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library’:

however, when I try to load the package: `library(tm)`, it shows me an error:

```
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘slam’
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tm’
```

Comment: `install.packages("tm",dependencies=TRUE)` or `install.packages("slam")` (and hope that there are no other dependencies that you missed)

Comment: feel free to post a version of my comment as a solution, once the time restriction expires

Comment: Correction... feel _obligated_ to post a version.

Answer (score 8):

The package has to be first installed before you load the package using **library()**. To install any package, open the `R` or `RStudio` shell and execute the following

```
install.packages("tm",dependencies=TRUE)
```

This will ask you to select the mirror and it will install it for you. If you use `RStudio`, you can easily do it from the `Tools` menu as shown below (`Tools -> Install Packages` -> **Name of the package** you want to install).
[image]

And then finally, you can invoke the **library("name of the package installed")** function.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `install.packages()`, my sense would be to recommend you call with the parameter `dependencies = TRUE`. This will install both the required library and its dependencies. Personally, I would avoid all the complexities and use the following solution:

```
requiredPackages <- c("ascii", "devtools","plyr","dplyr","tidyr")

ipak <- function(pkg)
{
  new.pkg <- pkg[!(pkg %in% installed.packages()[, "Package"])]
  if (length(new.pkg))
    install.packages(new.pkg, dependencies = TRUE)
  sapply(pkg, require, character.only = TRUE)
}

ipak(requiredPackages)
```

this code both checks if the package is installed and if not installed will install the library and its dependencies. It then loads the package via require(). nb. Personally, I prefer `require()` to `library()` as you can check the return code of a call to `require()`...

My sense is that the above code may make for easier code readability as it removes the need to have `library()` calls through the code.

I hope the above helps - happy new year

Comment: I don't understand why you are using length in this...? Could you please explain why you use this versus `exists("")`?

Comment: @user3553260 Look at the line above the 'if' clause. It filters the list passed in (pkg) thus if the length is 0 (False) do not install anything as all packages passed in to the function have been previously installed. It is important to only install the subset not already installed. You then drop through to check all the packages referenced are loaded by 'require'. The code both installs for and loads any packages. I hope that helps clarify things for you.

Comment: Interesting, I am new to the `if (false)` statement. That clears things up!