# Can't reference external R package from R.Net

Tags: c#, r, package, external

To leverage R from my .Net website, i'm using R.Net (1.5.13).
To some extend this is working fine for me, but when i'm trying to reference an external R package (the package: tm) i'm running into deep trouble.

The following C# code:

```
REngine engine = null;
REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables();
engine = REngine.GetINstance();
engine.Initialize();

engine.Evaluate(".libPaths('C:/Users/Laptop/Documents/R/win-library/3.1')");
engine.Evaluate("library(tm)");
```

is resulting in: *package or namespace load failed form 'tm'*

From RStudio the command *library(tm)* works without any exceptions.

I tried the following steps to solve this problem:

- a reinstall of R
- updating packages from R studio
- adding 'C:/Users/Laptop/Documents/R/win-library/3.1' to R_LIBS, R_LIBS_USER and R_LIBS_SITE

But nothing seems to help so far.

**Can someone help me with this nasty problem?**

Some information from *sessionInfo()*:

R version: 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)

Platform: x86_64_w64_mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

other attached packages:
[1] tm_0.5-10

Comment: dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530738/how-to-load-packages-in-r

Comment: Can you actually use the package in R? (outside of R.NET/C#)

Comment: Is it really "getINstance"? Because that makes me think you've not cut n pasted the actual code and you could have not posted the actual code that generates the actual problem. Post a minimal failing example which you think should work, not just a six-line snippet.

Comment: Mr. Flick, yes we can use the package in R without any problems. It seems to be a problem in R.Net or between R.Net and R.

Comment: Spacedman, the actual sourcecode is:  `string path = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Path");
            path = @"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.0\library;" + @"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.0\bin\i386;" + path;

            System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", path);
           
            REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables();
            engine = REngine.GetInstance();

            engine.Initialize();
            engine.Evaluate("library(tm)"); `

Answer (score 0):

The last two issues logged at the codeplex site, [here](http://rdotnet.codeplex.com/workitem/117) and [here](http://rdotnet.codeplex.com/workitem/116), relate to this problem: running R.NET from an IIS web app is a known long-standing issue. Thankfully, recently [skyguy94](http://www.codeplex.com/site/users/view/skyguy94) has done the best diagnosis and explanation of the issue to date, and as I understand proposes a workaround. You should give it a try.

Future versions of R.NET will likely offer an easier way to, er, accomodate IIS, but this is subject to the time of already busy volunteers. Meanwhile, I'll update the home page to flag the vexed issues running under IIS.

Comment: Skyguy94, thx a lot! I certainly will give it a try tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

There might be other base package/s that may be failing after the package shown in the error.

In my case matrixStats was failing but in the background stats was failing to load, and that was failing because it was trying to find core R dlls inside the stats library.

I fixed the issue from another post: http://author-entry17.rssing.com/chan-9456546/all_p43.html

You have to copy over the dlls from the architecture folder into the package path as a work around.

ie copy dlls in C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.0\bin\i386 or C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.0\bin\x64

to

R\R-3.3.1\library\stats\libs\x64 or R\R-3.3.1\library\stats\libs\i386

as a work around.